# Accessing elements in JSON for nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, json, parsing

first off I am very new to node/JSON, so please take that into consideration when reading through.

The purpose of this code is to take data from a SQL Server database, and be able to access the elements that it pulls. For example, it will pull several thousand parentacccount ID's, and I just want to access one of those.

I've browsed forums for almost the entire day trying to access JSON elements from my nodejs function, and I every time I try and access one of these elements I am hit with an "undefined" error. As a last resort I am here.

I have checked a few times to see recordset has been parsed, and it appears that it is being parsed.

Below is my code, and a very small example of the JSON code is towards the end.

I have commented where I am getting my error.

```
function getEmp() {
    var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
    var req = new sql.Request(conn);

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        req.query("SELECT * FROM parentaccount Where accountname like 'Titan%' FOR JSON PATH", function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                const Test1 = recordset[0].ParentAccountId; //error here
                console.log(Test1);
            }
            conn.close();
        })
    })
}

getEmp();





//EXAMPLE JSON
{ recordsets: [ [ [Object] ] ],
recordset:   
[ { 'JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B':
'[{"ParentAccountId":4241411,"AccountName":"Titan"} ],
output: {},
rowsAffected: [ 3 ] }



ERROR:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ParentAccountId' of undefined
    at C:\Users\za47387\Desktop\Excel Export Code\test2.js:31:48
    at _query (C:\Users\za47387\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1347:9)
    at Request.tds.Request.err [as userCallback] (C:\Users\za47387\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:671:15)
    at Request.callback (C:\Users\za47387\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:37:27)
    at Connection.endOfMessageMarkerReceived (C:\Users\za47387\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2104:20)
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\za47387\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1084:36)
    at Parser.tokenStreamParser.on (C:\Users\za47387\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:914:14)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Parser.parser.on.token (C:\Users\za47387\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:27:14)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:189:13)
```

Comment: just print recordset. What does it return ?

Comment: @ParthGhiya Hi Parth, recordset successfully prints out my entire query in json. However, I am looking to access just one single piece of the json data, rather than all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what the sample you have shared,

recordset[0] is undefined, meaning either two options :

a) the result for the query fetched no rows.
b) the result of the query is in a different format than expected.

though i suspect a), its good to console the output. kindly run the below code before you try accessing ParentAccountId.

```
console.log('output : ', JSON.stringify(recordset, null, 4));
```

also i would refactor the code to be :

```
const Test1 = (Array.isArray(recordset) && 
recordset.length) ? recordset[0].ParentAccountId : null;
```

so that the error won't make the nodejs process go down.

Comment: Hello, below is a sample of the output. I had to cut the json short, as some of the information is confidential.

`output :  {
    "recordsets": [
        [
            {
                "JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B": "[{\"ParentAccountId\":1764,\"AccountName\":\"Titan}]"
              }
]`

Comment: One thing worth noting, one of the options in the config has "encrypt" to true. It is a requirement for the database, so not sure if that might be causing an issue when trying to access it.

Comment: It turns out I am not getting valid JSON. Thanks for the help all.